# Checking validation results in Keras shows only 50% correct. Clearly random

Tags: image, validation, tensorflow, keras

I'm struggling with a, seemingly simple, problem. I can't figure out how to match my input images to the resulting probabilities produced by my model.

Training and Validation of my model (Vanilla `VGG16`, re-trainined for 2 classes, dogs and cats) are going fine, getting me close to 97% validation accuracy, but when I run the check to see what I got right and what I got wrong I only get random results.

**Found 1087 correct labels (53.08%)**

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the `ImageDataGenerator` which produces random batches on my validation images, although I DO set `shuffle = false`

I just save the filenames and classes of my generator before I run them and I ASSUME that the index of my filenames and classes is the same as the output of my probabilities.

Here's my setup (Vanilla VGG16, with last layer replaced to match 2 categories for cats and dogs)

```python
new_model.summary()
```

---

```python
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
Binary_predictions (Dense)   (None, 2)                 8194      
=================================================================
Total params: 134,268,738
Trainable params: 8,194
Non-trainable params: 134,260,544
_________________________________________________________________
```

```python
batch_size=16
epochs=3
learning_rate=0.01
```

This is the definition of the generators, for training and validation. I did not yet include the data augmentation part at this point.

```python
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
train_filenames = train_generator.filenames
train_samples = len(train_filenames)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    valid_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle = False) #Need this to be false, so I can extract the correct classes and filenames in order that that are predicted
validation_filenames = validation_generator.filenames
validation_samples = len(validation_filenames)
```

Finetuning the model goes fine

```python
#Fine-tune the model
#DOC: fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
#              validation_data=None, validation_steps=None, class_weight=None,
#              max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, initial_epoch=0)

new_model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_samples // batch_size)

Epoch 1/3
1434/1434 [==============================] - 146s - loss: 0.5456 - acc: 0.9653 - val_loss: 0.5043 - val_acc: 0.9678
Epoch 2/3
1434/1434 [==============================] - 148s - loss: 0.5312 - acc: 0.9665 - val_loss: 0.4293 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 3/3
1434/1434 [==============================] - 148s - loss: 0.5332 - acc: 0.9665 - val_loss: 0.4329 - val_acc: 0.9731
```

As is the extraction of the validation data

```python
#We need the probabilities/scores for the validation set
#DOC: predict_generator(generator, steps, max_queue_size=10, workers=1,
#                       use_multiprocessing=False, verbose=0)
probs = new_model.predict_generator(
            validation_generator,
            steps=validation_samples // batch_size,
            verbose = 1)

#Extracting the probabilities and labels
our_predictions = probs[:,0]
our_labels = np.round(1-our_predictions)
expected_labels = validation_generator.classes
```

Now, when I calculate the success of my validation set by comparing the expected labels and the calculated labels, I get something that is suspiciously close to random:

```python
correct = np.where(our_labels==expected_labels)[0]
print("Found {:3d} correct labels ({:.2f}%)".format(len(correct),
       100*len(correct)/len(our_predictions)))
```

**Found 1087 correct labels (53.08%)**

Clearly this is not correct.

I suspect this is something to do with the randomness of the Generators, but I set shuffle = False.

This code was DIRECTLY copied from the Fast.ai course by the great Jeremy Howard, but I can't get it to work anymore..

I am using Keras 2.0.8 and TensorFlow 1.3 backend on Python 3.5 under Anaconda...

Please help me retain my sanity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met a similar problem before, I think `predict_generator()` is not friendly, so I write a function to test the data set.
Here is my code snippet:

```python
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import json

def get_img_result(img_path):
image = Image.open(img_path)
image.load()
image = image.resize((img_width, img_height))
if image.mode is not 'RGB':
    image = image.convert('RGB')
array = np.asarray(image, dtype='int32')
array = array / 255
array = np.asarray([array])
result = new_model.predict(array)
print(result)
return result

# path: the root folder of the validation data set. validation->cat->kitty.jpg
def validate(path):
result_list = []
right_count = 0
wrong_count = 0
categories = os.listdir(path)
for i in range(len(categories)):
    images = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, categories[i]))
    for image in images:
        result = get_img_result(os.path.join(path, categories[i], image))[0]
        if result[i] != max(result):
            result_list.append({'image': image, 'category': categories[i], 'score': result.tolist(), 'right': 0})
            wrong_count = wrong_count + 1
        else:
            result_list.append({'image': image, 'category': categories[i], 'score': result.tolist(), 'right': 1})
            right_count = right_count + 1
json_string = json.dumps(result_list)
with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_string)
print('right count : {0} \n wrong count : {1} \n accuracy : {2}'.format(right_count, wrong_count,
                                                                        (right_count) / (
                                                                            right_count + wrong_count)))
```

I use `PIL` convert image to numpy array as Keras do, I test all images and save the result into a json file.

Wish it helps.

Comment: Sure does! Still find it weird it is so difficult for a task so fundamental

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `validation_generator.reset()` in between `fit_generator()` and `predict_generator()`.

In `*_generator()` functions, data batches are inserted into a queue before being used to fit/evaluate the model. The underlying queue is always kept full, so there will be some extra batches in the queue when training ends. You can verify it by printing `validation_generator.batch_index` after training. Therefore, your `predict_generator()` does not start with the first batch, and `probs[0]` is not the prediction of the first image. That's why `our_labels` does not align with `expected_labels` and the accuracy is low.

BTW, you should use `validation_steps=validation_samples // batch_size + 1` (also for the training generator). Unless `validation_samples` is a multiple of `batch_size`, you're ignoring one batch in each epoch if you use `validation_steps=validation_samples // batch_size`, and your model is evaluated on a (slightly) different dataset in each epoch.

Comment: Thanks! This makes total sense now. BTW I indeed figured out the +1 issue since I figured I would miss out on one batch

Comment: @thondeboer, If the issue has been resolved, please accept the relevant answer so that others know it's resolved.

Comment: Thanks Yu-Yang! I had different results on subsequent predictions with the generator and could solve it thanks to you. Very much appreciated.