# Prevent predict_generator from shuffling batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to check the performance of my model on the validation-dataset. As such, I am using `predict_generator` to return predictions from my `validation_generator`. However, I am not able to match the predictions with true labels returned from `validation_generator.classes` since the order of my predictions is mixed up.

This is how I initialize my generator:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                                    validation_split=0.20)

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(main_path, target_size=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_SIZE), shuffle=False, seed=13,
                                                     class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, subset="training")

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(main_path, target_size=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_SIZE), shuffle=False, seed=13,
                                                     class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, subset="validation")

#Found 4473 images belonging to 3 classes.
#Found 1116 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

Now I am using the predict_generator like so:

```
validation_steps_per_epoch = np.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=validation_steps_per_epoch)
```

I realize that there is a mismatch between my validation-data size (=1116) and validation_steps_per_epoch (=1152). Since these two dont match, I find the output `predictions` is different each time I run model.predict_generator(...).

Is there any way to fix this besides changing batch_size to 1 in order to make sure that generator steps through all samples?

I found someone with a similar issue here [keras predict_generator is shuffling its output when using a keras.utils.Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088826/keras-predict-generator-is-shuffling-its-output-when-using-a-keras-utils-sequenc), however his solution does not fix my problem since I am not writing any custom functions.

Comment: @AsronDT Did you find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no randomization or shuffling going on, what happens is that since the batch size of the validation generator does not exactly divide the number of samples, then the leftover samples spill into the next time the generator is called, which messes up everything.

What you could do is set a batch size for the validation generator that divides exactly the number of validation samples, or set the batch size to one.

Comment: I had a similar problem with putting a small set of  test images through a pre-trained model.  However, I observed that just setting the batch size to one does not fix this shuffling without also having `shuffle=False` in the generator (which you already have...I just wanted to put this out there for others who might have had the same problem I did).  However, in case it is helpful, I note that [Keras #6745](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6745) describes this problem, which is allegedly fixed in [PR #6891](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/6891).